# Why is load balancing not working in this server?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, redhat

I'm trying to set up a load balancing using Apache and reverse proxy pattern. But I'm facing some issues. When trying the configuration, an HTTP 403 error is being responded. This is the configuration I'm trying:

```
Listen 9104

<Location "/balancer-manager">
    SetHandler balancer-manager
    Allow from all
</Location>

<VirtualHost *:9104>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    ServerName appempmam.desabpd.popular.local
    <Proxy balancer://mycluster>
        BalancerMember "http://10.15.5.152:9100/"  route=1
        #BalancerMember "http://0.0.0.0:8081/"  route=2
        ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
    
    </Proxy>

    
    
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/proxy-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/proxy-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

If I replace the `proxypass` and `proxypassreverse` entries with the actual backend server instead of the cluster name, then it works and requests get responded correctly, but when using the load balancing it won't work. I searched for any kind of error in the logs but couldn't find anything. I need the balancing to work since another server will be added in the near future. Am I missing something here?

I'm using Apache 2.4 and Red Hat 8.1.

BTW, this is the directories permissions entries in the main conf file:

```
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
#    Require all granted
</Directory>
```